# How to escape or break the chain flow in underscore/lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Here is a lodash chain that returned an ordered, uniquely sorted array of integer. Because the input can not be fully trusted, there are intermediate validation (thanks to the thru method in this example). How can this example be changed in order to break the chain flow and return ?

```js
_.mixin({
  isIntegerString: function(arg) {
    return /^\d+$/.test(arg);
  }
});

var a = _.chain(" 54,32 ,6 ,32 ") // but param here can be anything so I have to do some checkings
 .thru(function(untrusted) {return _.isString(untrusted) ? untrusted : ''}) // validation !
 .split(',')
 .map(_.trim)
 .thru(function(array1) {return _.every(array1, _.isIntegerString) ? array1 : []}) // validation !
 .map(_.parseInt)
 .sortBy(function(e) {return e;})
 .uniqBy(function(e) {return e;})
 .value();

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: My two pennies' worth is that the validation should be done independently of the transform and filter of valid data i.e. not in the chain. Also afaik you can't shortcut a chain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot do what you're asking for using _.chain. Nevertheless, I suggest taking a look at this interesting [article](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba#.gtpqbdmqu) about _.chain and lodash.

Following the approach of the article, you could use function composition and short-circuit when the result of a function is false. I don't know if lodash offers a built-in solution to this, I just did it myself for fun's sake. Of course, it's just a naive approach to the problem and could greatly be improved.

Hope it helps.

```js
function checkIsString(untrusted) {
  return _.isString(untrusted) ? untrusted : false;
}

function checkAreAllIntegers(array1) {
  return _.every(function(arg) {
    return /^\d+$/.test(arg);
  })(array1) ? array1 : false;
}

function overEveryFnc() {
  var arrFnc = _.toArray(arguments);
  return function applyNextFncTo(args) {
    var nextFnc = arrFnc.shift(),
      partialRes;

    return nextFnc && (partialRes = nextFnc(args)) ? applyNextFncTo(partialRes) : args;
  };
}

var b = overEveryFnc(
  checkIsString,
  //_.tap(console.log),
  _.split(','),
  _.map(_.trim),
  //_.tap(console.log),
  checkAreAllIntegers,
  _.map(_.parseInt(10)),
  //_.tap(console.log),
  _.sortBy(_.identity),
  _.uniqBy(_.identity))(" 54,32 ,6 ,32 ");

console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `flow` and being inspired by Elixir, I've come up with something like this:

```ts
import { curryRight, head, isString, flow } from 'lodash/fp'

enum MaybeEnum {
    Just,
    Nothing
}

type Just = [MaybeEnum.Just, any]

type Nothing = [MaybeEnum.Nothing]

type Maybe = Just | Nothing

type Func = ( parameter: Maybe ) => Maybe

const from = ( value: any ) => [MaybeEnum.Just, value]

const apply = curryRight( ( value: Maybe, func: Func ) => {
    if ( head( value ) === MaybeEnum.Nothing ) {
        return value
    }

    return func( value )
} )

const validateIsString = ( [_, value]: Maybe ): Maybe => {
    if ( !isString( value ) ) {
        console.log( 'not a string' )

        return [MaybeEnum.Nothing]
    }

    return [MaybeEnum.Just, value]
}

const doSomething = ( [_, value]: Maybe ): Maybe => {
    console.log( 'value is', value )

    return value
}

export const chainyChain = () => {
    const chain = flow( [
        apply( validateIsString ),
        apply( doSomething ),
    ] )

    chain( from( 'Hello' ) )
    chain( from( [] ) )
}
```

Simply replace the `MaybeEnum` with an object literal for js.